# parsing xml in angular2 to be rendered in the view

Tags: javascript, html, xml, angular

Do I need to parse my xml to get the data from the xml to render in the html? I'm currently getting a local .xml file using `http.get` request and in console log its showing all the information that's in the xml file I think its just reading it.

Question is how to convert xml into json format in angular2?

I tried the `console.log(data.title)` but this is returning me as `unidentified`

```
getXml() {
   this.http.get('../../xmlConf/dashboard_journey.xml')
    .map(response => response.text())
    .subscribe(data => {
        if(data) {
            console.log('fetching your xml');
            console.log(data); // this shows me everything
        }
    });
}
```

xml

```
<xml>
<journey>
    <title>Click and Collect</title>
    <shortDesc>
        <short_desc_1>lorem</short_desc_1>
        <short_desc_2>lorem</short_desc_2>
    </shortDesc>
    <longDesc>
        lorem
    </longDesc>
    <imageName>
        <img src="/journey_images/clickandcollect.jpg" alt="Click and Collect"/>
    </imageName>
</journey>
```

Using the answer below

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
```

console.log of the above code:

[image]

Currently doing for loop to iterate the parsed xml, however in my view its only giving me one object. ngFor only iterates objects that is in an array.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= newFormat.childNodes.length; i++) {
                this.title = newFormat.getElementsByTagName('title')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                this.desc = newFormat.getElementsByTagName('desc')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                console.log(this.title + ' = ' +  this.desc);
            }
```

view:

```
<li>{{ title }}</li>
```

Comment: What happens when you give, `console.log(data[0].title)`

Comment: if I do data[0] its only showing me < so I think I need to convert this xml into json.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

You simply pass your data variable to DOMParser then you can access elements by reference

**Example**

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
```

Comment: I console log xmlData and its giving me a json format, but xml stuff is nested inside #document and couldn't access the elements like title, longDesc when I do xmlData.title or longDesc

Comment: see my edit in my post above, that's still an xml not json fomat. Really want to avoid doing for each in each tag just to return it.

Comment: On my phone atm but try xmlData.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

Comment: yeah that's how I'm doing it atm see my for loop code in my original post above.