# Read a xml file and display as text using angular 2,

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying on various sources but i count see a single tutorial or piece of code. Im a beginner . thanks in advance

Comment: A few threads about this: [How to parse xml in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368405/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-2), [Read xml file data in angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577492/read-xml-file-data-in-angular2), [parsing xml in angular2 to be rendered in the view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765805/parsing-xml-in-angular2-to-be-rendered-in-the-view). Please search before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered troubles when I wanted to parse XML then there is a quick example to achieve it.

In one of my project, I used [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js).

Install it and then you can, for example, use it like this:

```
parseXML : any = require('xml2js');

this.parseXML.parseString(xmlToParse, (err: any, res: any) => {
    console.log(res); //res contains your parsed XML
}
```

Comment: i want to fetch a xml from url and parse it , it tried http get but i coudnt parse

Comment: You need a simple http get, look at the data you receive, maybe you need to just get an attribute